# PrintWriter what do wait and notify methods do?

Tags: java, android, printwriter

I read android documentation (which is clear as mud) and it says that:

**wait**

> Causes the calling thread to wait until another thread calls the notify() or notifyAll() method of this object.

**notify**

> Causes a thread which is waiting on this object's monitor (by means of calling one of the wait() methods) to be woken up.

Does that mean that:

```
public synchronized void myAwesomeFunction (PrintWriter out, String[] data)
{
    for (String d : data)
    {
        out.wait();
        out.println (d);
        out.flush();
        out.notify();
    }
}
```

would wait until `PrintWriter` finish sending the first string and then move to the next one? or did i get it completely wrong?

Comment: I suggest you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html Note that this isn't really to do with `PrintWriter` - these are methods defined on `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object in Java can be used as a lock. These methods are inherited from the `Object` class, and are useful for synchronization between threads. They are completely unrelated to the PrintWriter functionality.

println() is a blocking function - it does not return until it has finished sending the first string (ignoring buffering). Simply writing this:

```
out.println(d);
System.out.println("'d' has finished writing");
```

Is all you need to achieve the same effect. Using `wait` and `notify` is useful when you want one thread to wait for another, and is not normally useful within the same thread.

Comment: I have a problem sending multiple strings in a loop using printwriter through a socket where it sends only the first string, why is it doing that since println blocks until it's finished?

Comment: PrintWriter also buffers lines, for efficiency. It flushes these buffers either when you `close` it, or when you call `flush` (but you should trust `close`, don't call flush just for the sake of it).